# Spec of a finitely generated $k$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, with $k$ an algebraically closed field.

I've read that there is a bijective correspondence between points in $Spec(R)$ and $k$-algebra homomorphisms between $R$ and $k$. How is this realized?

Comment: Remark: If $R$ is *any* commutative ring, then there is a bijection between points in $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and classes of ring homomorphisms $R \to k$, where $k$ runs through all possible fields, where we identify $R \to k$ with $R \to k'$ if there is some field $L$ with morphisms $k \to L \leftarrow k'$ such that the obvious square commutes. Actually, this makes it possible to define the underlying set $|X|$ of any functor $X : \mathsf{CRing} \to \mathsf{Set}$, namely as $\mathrm{colim}_{k \text{ field}} X(k)$, in such a way that $|\hom(R,-)|=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

Answer (score 2):

More like between points in $\text{Max}(R) \subset {Spec}(R)$ and $k$-algebra homomorphisms from $R$ to $k$.

For every homomorphism $\phi \colon R \to k$ its kernel is a maximal ideal, that is, a point in $\text{Max}(R)$.

Conversely, given a maximal ideal $m\subset R$ the canonical morphism of $k$-algebras
$R \to R/m$ gives in fact a morphism from $R$ to $k$. Indeed, the composition
$$k \to R \to R/m$$ is an isomorphism, because $k$ is algebraically closed and $R$ is finitely generated ( Hilbert's Nullstellensatz).